# Fast blur is marked as Legacy in CC 2018. What's the best (and/or fastest) equivalent to use now?

Tags: after-effects

Fast blur is marked as Legacy in CC 2018. What's the best (and/or fastest) equivalent to use now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gaussian Blur is now GPU accelerated, and it's the one that they suggest as the successor to fast blur. They've even included a script to update old projects to use the new blur, look for it in **file>Scripts>UpgradeLegacyBlurs**.

If you want one that uses the same maths as fast blur, i.e. is the most visually similar, then I think Box Blur is the one.

The official announcement is [here](https://theblog.adobe.com/after-effects-cc-2015-3-in-depth-gpu-accelerated-effects).

Answer (score 0):

Gaussian Blur is now GPU accelerated, and it's the one that they suggest as the successor to fast blur. They've even included a script to update old projects to use the new blur, look for it i